# Framework similar to Android SDK for developing (mobile) web apps

Tags: android, web-applications, gwt, frameworks

Is there any framework, similar to Android SDK, for developing (mobile) web apps? I mean something as simple, integrated and complete like Android SDK + Eclipse but not for Android platform but for browser platform. GWT seems to be quite close to what I am looking for.

Comment: And if GWT "seems to be quuite close to what I am looking for", why aren't you going with GWT? :)

Comment: I don't know, perhaps there is something better ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a cross-platform framework, check this out:

http://mashable.com/2010/08/11/cross-platform-mobile-development-tools/

Keep one thing in mind:  aside from the issue of how well these work, experience with one of these cross-platform frameworks will not help you get a job at a shop that does native device development (they may even laugh at you in the interview).

**Update:**  Er, I reread your question and realized you're trying to do web development rather than cross-platform.  Maybe this will be of some use:

http://desizntech.info/2010/04/10-free-and-useful-ide-for-programmers-and-developers-2/